# Select2 -> Dynamic input returns as a string (jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-select2

The format for my select 2 is as such:

```
$("#selectPretty").select2({
    tokenSeparators: [","], 
    tags:["1", "2", "3", "php", "tiger", "test", "big bang theory", "bikes", "gh", "sd", "cheese", "food", "name", "jack", "chickens", "yikes!", "testing", "this", "is", "a", "questionj", "new", "question", "s"]
});
```

Which shows as such:

[image]

BUT, when I try to assign data into the box dynamically through AJAX by using this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "grabTags.php",
    data: "tags="+$("#selectPretty").val(),
    success: 
        function(msg2) {
            alert(msg2);
            $("#selectPretty").select2({
                tokenSeparators: [","],
                tags:[msg2]
            });
        }
});
```

It will come out like so:

[image]

For some reason the whole string is one option and I can't make it explode the result into different options...

Does anyone know what I can do here?

Note that 'tags:[msg2]' is returned from my grabTags.php file and 'msg2' = "1", "2", "3, etc...

Kindest Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried splitting the string that comes back from the PHP?

You can invoke the `split` method on a string (such as that which is returned from your PHP) and pass it a separator (in your case a `,`).

Something like this should work:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "grabTags.php",
    data: "tags="+$("#selectPretty").val(),
    success: 
        function(msg2) {
            //at this point, msg2 is the string: '"1","2","3"'

            var myTags = msg2.split(',');
            //myTags is now the array: ["1","2","3"]

            $("#selectPretty").select2({

                //tags needs to be an array, so pass in myTags
                tags: myTags 
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seemed to work. What exactly does this do to make it work though? I don't understand!

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem. I have updated my answer to provide a bit more explanation. Please let me know if it still doesn't make sense :)

Answer (score 0):

The Select2 `tags` need a javascript *array*, not just a string surrounded by brackets.

So server side, have PHP spit out a json encoded array:

```
$tags = array("1", "2", "3", "php", "tiger", "test", "big bang theory", "bikes", "gh", "sd", "cheese", "food", "name", "jack", "chickens", "yikes!", "testing", "this", "is", "a", "questionj", "new", "question", "s");
echo json_encode($tags);
```

Now client side take that response in your ajax `success` handler, and assign it directly to `tags`.

Note that you may need to set `dataType` to `json` in your ajax call so that jQuery automatically parses the response as json. Not sure if it will figure that out on its own or not.

You may also be able to get rid of `tokenSeparators` if you provide an actual array as your tags.

Comment: I tried exactly as you stated and I set the datatype etc but it didn't seem to fix the issue. Instead it'd output this:
http://puu.sh/5kdo5.png

In the documentation is states that the format needs to be "word", "word2" - Not sure if it matters that it's a json array instead. 

Am I doing something wrong by any chance?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What's the output from your PHP script? It should look like this: http://3v4l.org/53MHH.

Comment: This may help: http://jsfiddle.net/cFRnu/. It doesn't do the ajax call, I'm manually pretending to have an ajax result. However you can see how, assuming your ajax response is valid and parsed properly, you can easily hand it to Select2 like I'm doing.

Comment: Hi, the output from my PHP script is this: ' {"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"php","10":"tiger","12":"chickens"}' (Without single quotes at either end) which I assume is the wrong format? I see what you're doing in your fiddle but I'm still getting the same output. I really appreciate your help btw!

EDIT: It's been fixed now. Thanks a lot for your help! Appreciate it :)